# Typescript extend "a type nested in a type"

Tags: typescript, graphql, codegen

I am have the following type:

```
type IQueryResolvers<ContextType = any, ParentType extends {} = {}> = {
me?: ...
profile?: ... 
}
```

the problem is, I have one controller function for each key of type IQueryResolvers, for example:

```
const meController = () => {};
```

I would like access the type like this:

```
const meController: IQueryResolvers.me = () => {};
```

Does anyone has the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is:

```
const meController: IQueryResolvers['me'] = () => {};
```